# Send an image from android app to localhost

Tags: android, python, flask

I want to send an Image to a localhost using a button in android a android app.At localhost that image pass to a model developed in python.

After do a process using the image,the model give an output to the android app. That result getting part is working fine.

I want to know how to do the image sending part ?

or suggestion for another way to do that process.

This is the code in the model that get an image which we copy to test folder in the pc. I want to develop this to get image from android app .

```
def process_test_data():
testing_data = []
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):
    path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR,img)
    img_num = img.split('.')[0]
    img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
    testing_data.append([np.array(img), img_num])
    print("\n****testing_data********",testing_data)
shuffle(testing_data)
np.save('test_data.npy', testing_data)
return testing_data
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what library you are using to connect to the internet. But for sending pictures, I would suggest first to convert it to Base64 text and send that. Python will sure know how to deal with it.

```
    fun bitmapToBase64StringInline(bitmap: Bitmap): String {
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream)
        val bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
        return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }
```

Also, it is good to do it in a separate thread and watch out for OOM exception when using large images.
To send it, use some good connection library like OkHttp, Volley, Retrofit etc. Or, just implement kinda basic AsyncTask like this:

```
protected void doInBackground(String... params) {  
URL url = new URL(yourTextUrl);


        try {
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(MyConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(MyConstants.READ_TIMEOUT);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.connect();
                    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                    String out = params[0];
                    Log.d("Uploading this: ", out);
                    writer.write(out);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERR", e.getMessage());
            if (null != e.getMessage() && e.getMessage().equals("timeout")) {
                this.cancel(true);
            }
        } finally {
                connection.disconnect(); 
        }
}
```

> **connection** is either HttpURLConnection or Http**s**URLConnection, based on
>   your protocol.

I hope it's clear enough.